# Need Devexpress v11.1.7 setup important

Tags: devexpress

My customer help from me for revision some parts of they project code. But they have only source code, havent devexpress 2011 v11.1.7 setup. I upgrade devexpress version but some referance dll is compiled with dexpress v11.1.7. When i rebuild, i get error about devexpress version. I cant remove dll because so many function and form on this dlls.
Please share me this devexpress version.Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

0. If you have the license of DevExpress then you are avaliable to download 11.1.7 version directly from their [Download Manager](https://www.devexpress.com/ClientCenter/DownloadManager/):

[image: Download Manager]

1. If you haven't license, then you need to get one and follow the step 0.

Comment: Thank u for answer.

I havent licence. Can u send me only this setup.

Comment: @ZaferGezen I can't send you this setup because of license violation. You can try to ask DevExpress directly for this setup.